# Htaccess mod rewrite?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I created two folders "**production**" and "**development**". I wonder how can I use **.htaccess** to point the domain and subdomain to the appointed directory **without changing the url**.

Example (without changing the url on browser)

```
mydomain.com => mydomain.com/production
dev.mydomain.com => mydomain.com/development
```

Folder structure:

```
public_html
|
|
|- production
|
|- development
```

Comment: Better to change their `DocumentRoot` in Apache config

Comment: I'm using a shared hosting. Don't have rights to modify that config :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!production/).*) production/$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!development/).*) development/$1 [L,NC]
```